# Remove last items of Sets type in Redis

Tags: notifications, redis

I use Sets type of Redis to store number of items `Notification Ids`, For example :

```
SADD bookNotify:user:1 "1"
SADD bookNotify:user:1 "2"
SADD bookNotify:user:1 "3"
SADD bookNotify:user:1 "4"
SADD bookNotify:user:1 "8"
```

How I can remove last of three items?What is the best structure and data type for `CRUD` notification in redis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Redis' Sets are unordered, the very notion of "last elements" is meaningless for these.

I recommend looking into Sorted Sets (follow the trail of ZADD), perhaps using epoch values as scores.